# What workarounds exist for the lack of Layer Styles in Photoshop Elements 10?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

Since Elements doesn't have the per-layer Blending Options feature, I'm wondering how other Elements users deal with this restriction.

*Edit*: this question was originally posted on *photo.stackexchange.com* but since I'm looking for a graphic design-oriented answer the question has been migrated here.

Comment: Are you referring to blending modes like Multiply, Screen, Overlay and so forth?

Comment: No, I'm referring to that dialog where you can enable Drop Shadow, Bevel/Emboss and other effects on a layer. [This](http://www.webdesign.org/photoshop/photoshop-basics/blending-options.13410.html)?

Comment: Ah.  I never realised the menu says Blending Options, but those are what are more commonly referred to as Layer Styles.  What version of Elements?  It seems version 9 has layer styles.

Comment: Never mind, sorry, I see in your title you specified version 10.

Comment: Can you explain how you are wanting to use this in the context of photo editing? Usually effects like drop shadows or bezels are more about graphic design, and you might get more help if we migrate this question to the Stack Exchange site for that. (It's also the answer the the question of why Adobe might have left this out of the more photo-focused Elements.)

Comment: @mattdm: You're right, I'm not using it for photo editing. I was just looking for a StackExchange site that covered Photoshop and I realize now that I may have targeted my question incorrectly. I'll accept the photo-centric answer below and repost my question on the graphic design site.

Comment: @Pieter — no problem. let's flag it to be migrated rather than reposting.

Comment: My guses is they don't use that software. Most other products at least offer layer blending options (though not the layer fx feature): The GIMP, Paint.Net, Pixelmator, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photoshop Elements 9 has layer styles under the Window > Effects menu.  See this article here
[How to Add Shadow and Glow Effects in Photoshop Elements 9](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-add-shadow-and-glow-effects-in-photoshop-el.html)

Comment: This answer the question about layer effects, but the original question is talking about layer blending. So confused. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The way users deal with or workaround it is by using what few effects are built in as MikeW mentioned. You can manually create some of the effects with some work. Like painting a drop shadow and blurring and lowering the opacity but this can be difficult and time consuming.

You could look at GIMP to try some effects that you cannot achieve easily in PSE.

Comment: While Gimp is very powerful, it _also_ doesn't have this particular feature. I didn't put it on my [list of photography-related things missing from Gimp](http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/7691/1943) because it's really a design and image creation feature rather than a photographic tool. From the roadmap, I see that (like adjustment layers) it's targetted for Gimp 3.2, which is probably several years off.

Comment: @mattdm - I did not know that. I looked at GIMP early on but already was into PS and did not use it anymore. Thanks for the info.